# Why Flutter (dart) is so slow to process images?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this method, that loads a photo from the user's phone to memory, resizes it and encodes it as JPEG:

```
List<int> processPersonProfilePhoto(File file) {
  var rawPhoto = file.readAsBytesSync();
  var jpg = Image.decodeJpg(rawPhoto);
  jpg = Image.copyResize(jpg, 512);
  return Image.encodeJpg(jpg, quality: 70);
}
```

I am running the method above on a separated isolate, via:

```
var jpgByteArray = await compute(processPersonProfilePhoto, file);
```

This whole process sometimes takes 20 - 30 seconds (the release mode is even worse than debug) and I am running on middle and high end devices.

This is the package I am using to process:

```
image: ^2.0.7
```

What am I doing wrong? How to improve that?

PS.: I done some more debugging and realized that the line that takes much longer to process is the deconding one:

```
var jpg = Image.decodeJpg(rawPhoto);
```

Comment: What model of phone are you running it on?

Comment: debug mode is slow, try release version

Comment: @Dylan I am testing on middle and high end devices. The processing times does not differentiate too much from debug to release modes.

Comment: I'm using the same package, my original image is around 800KB and the resized image is about 100KB, and it takes around 3 seconds to process.  how large is your original and resized images?

Comment: And I'm using low end real Android device

Comment: Did you try to put this as an issue on the github page for the plugin?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Nope, I am trying to understand if this is something I am doing wrong before annoying them with an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that this is a library issue. You can track the problem on the lib's github page, there are a lot of issues complaining about the slowness. (https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/104)

Until it gets fixed, use that library instead:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_image_compress

Edit: Seems now that the library has fixed the slowness problem on RELEASE builds: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/104#issuecomment-490794535