# Image processing in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I create app which recognize elements from picture. 
Now I have image in File class and I want to rotate image about few degrees and again have image in File class. 
Is there any solution how to resolve this?

P.S I don't want display this image. I must pass image as File object to some method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To rotate the actual file in memory use the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image#-readme-tab-)
>    library and the copyRotate function.

```
Image copyRotate(Image src, num angle, {
   Interpolation interpolation = Interpolation.nearest
  }
);
//Returns a copy of the [src] image, rotated by [angle] degrees.
```

Example:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
void main() {
  // Read an image from file (webp in this case).
  // decodeImage will identify the format of the image and use the appropriate
  // decoder.
  Image image = decodeImage(File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync());

  Image thumbnail = copyRotate(image, 120);

  // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
  File('thumbnail.png').writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));
}
```

[source](https://pub.dev/packages/image#-readme-tab-)

> To display a rotated version of the image stored, you can use a `RotationTransition` with an `AlwaysStoppedAnimation` like-

```
new RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1,
  child: new Text("Lorem ipsum")
)
```

or the `Transform.rotate()` widget like-

```
  Transform.rotate(angle: - math.pi / 4, child: Text("Text"),);
```

for your use case-

```
  Transform.rotate(angle: degrees*3.14/180, child: Image.asset("file_path"),);
```

Comment: I don't want display this image. I want to have rotated image as File object.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This solution works but when image from camera has size 4MB,  decoding this image takes about 30 sec, and next encoding about 10 sec. This is unacceptable in my app :/  . I think that exist solution which take less time but I can't find anything.

Comment: Did it take that long in debug mode or in release mode?

Comment: I measured time in release mode :/

Comment: [see this about the processing time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621239/why-flutter-dart-is-so-slow-to-process-image). Mark my answer as accepted if you think my answer helped you .

Comment: Is there any way to update the image being shown with the new file stored in memory instead of using Transform or RotatedBox?

Comment: @Chris please see the first part of my answer.