# Flutter: crop File (image) as a circle

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to crop a File (imagefile) in flutter.
This is what I have:

[image: uncropped image]

This is what I would like to get after crop (a png with circle crop)

[image: cropped image]

It's important that the file is png, so it doesn't have white borders.

Is there a package that support this?

Comment: maybe you can use ClipRRect https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html

Comment: thanks! but I don't need to display the image, i really need to crop it.

Comment: Did jazzbpn's solution work? `canvas.drawImage` draws nothing without a UI for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These simple steps get the required result.

Create a **PictureRecorder**.

Create a Canvas with your **PictureRecorder**.

Draw circle in canvas using **canvas.drawCircle()**.

Call **endRecording()** on the PictureRecorder to get a Picture.

Call **toImage()** on the Picture.

Convert image **toByteData()** .

**Save image locally** using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() ,only if you want to save.

[FULL ANSWER with SOURCE CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434412/how-to-crop-circularor-square-or-hexagon-area-from-canvas-in-flutter)

Answer (score 15):

You can use [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) to crop the image to be displayed on the Widget.

```dart
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    color: Colors.white,
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: AssetImage('assets/image.jpeg'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [simple image cropping package](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_image_crop#-readme-tab-) 
Which supports cropping the actual file.

You can also refer to my answer on [rotating images in files using dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413941/image-processing-in-dart/59414246#59414246).

Comment: How do you use the package to circle crop without a widget, no UI related? The gif shows circle crop still generates a rectangular file.